# How can I typeset vDash in plain TeX?

Tags: symbols, plain-tex, relation-symbols

I am working on a model theory document in plain TeX, and I use the vdash and vDash symbols a lot.

`\vdash` is already part of plain TeX, so no problem, but what's the way to get `\vDash` to look consistent with it (same height, good alignment, etc.)?

```
*\show\vdash
> \vdash=\mathchar"3260.
*\show\vDash
> \vDash=undefined.
```

For the time being I use `\def\vDash{\mathrel{|\!\!\!=}}`, but that's ugly.

Comment: `\input amssym` and `\vDash` will do.

Comment: @egreg This is great, thank you

Answer (score 2):

The `\vDash` is common character in math, so it is supported in almost all Unicode math fonts. You can load Unicode math font and use it. For example in OpTeX:

```
\fontfam[lm]

$\vDash$

\bye
```

The idea to load `amssym` is the way to old days when we didn't have Unicode.

Answer (score 2):

The AMS provides support for its symbol font (the analog in LaTeX is `\usepackage{amssym}`.

The file to input is `amssym.tex`.

```
\input amssym

$A \vDash B$

\bye
```

[image]